# C# Pop3 DeleteMessage does not delete email

Tags: c#, pop3

Actually i would like to delete a mail message by mail unique id (i use ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Pop3Client)

To do so i use the following code :

```
private void DeleteMessageByUID ( string uid , Pop3Client popClient )
{
     for (int i = 1; i <= popClient.MessageCount; i++)
     {
          Header email = popClient.RetrieveHeaderObject(i);

          if (email.MessageId == uid )
          {
                popClient.DeleteMessage(i);
                break;
          }
     }

     popClient.Disconnect();
}
```

But after about two hour starting from when i delete all messages (initally the messages disappear from mailbox) i will able to find them back (with the same UIDs as the previously deleted messages).

I am not sure if the cause of the problem is in my program, i guess is a missconfiguration of the mailbox, but i would be sure about that before i contact the sysadmin.

Comment: The code is fine. I'd check with administrator for your email retention policies. Maybe you can't delete the messages and they must remain on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way POP3 works is that the DELE command that is sent by the `DeleteMessage()` method doesn't actually delete the message, all it does is mark it for future deletion when the POP3 client disconnects using the QUIT command.

I'm not sure how ActiveUp's POP3 client works, but mine ([MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)) will only send the QUIT command if you call `client.Disconnect (true);` (`true` is the quit argument).

Also, FWIW, the Message-Id header is not the same as a unique id. Be careful using that as your mechanism for identifying messages in any sort of unique way as Message-Ids are not necessarily unique nor is it a secure way of identifying messages. Clients that use Message-Ids in this way are open to DoS attacks where a hacker can send you an email with an identical Message-Id and force you to map it to the wrong message.

Comment: i have check how ActiveUp's Disconnect is implemented and seem that it doesn't take any parameters and always send back "QUIT" command to the Pop3 server (returning the server response as string).

Another question, i have not understand is the concern about Message-Id, can you send me a link where is explained this scenario? 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: If you send an email message with a Message-Id of 'X' and I, as a sabateur, want to subvert your message, I can send another message using the same Message-Id. If the recipient's client assumes that your message is a duplicate of mine (mine arrives first) because it has the same Message-Id, then the recipient never sees your message.

Comment: thanks now is clear in what the issue consist, is not my scenario.
I am developing a simple tool for automatic mail exchange, but it work on a private netowork and between "trusted" parties.
Thanks again for the clarifiation.